# Drupal 6 how do page-customnamehere.tpl.php work

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm working with a drupal 6.26 install.  I can see file names like `page-2011-custom-landing-page.tpl.php` in the theme directory I'm using.

From what I understand, I should be able to see this template at `http://www.mydomain.com/2011-custom-landing-page` however I just get a 'page not found' message at that address.  What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

> If you see a file name as 'page-2011-custom-landing-page.tpl.php' in you theme folder it means that there is a template file named 'page-2011-custom-landing-page.tpl.php' using for a page. That page may be defined in one of your custom module.

**Like this:**

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function custommodulename_menu() {
  $items['pathname'] = array(
    'title' => 'title', 
    'page callback' => 'custommodulename_pagename', 
    'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}


/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 * Adds our theme specificiations to the Theme Registry.
 */
function custommodulename_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $items = array();
  $items['custommodulename_pagename_page'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'template' => 'page-2011-custom-landing-page', //name of file(template) to be created,here create page-2011-custom-landing-page.tpl.php in the custom module folder
  );
  return $items;
}



/**
 * Callback function(menu)
 */

function custommodulename_pagename(){
  return theme('custommodulename_pagename_page');
}
?>
```

> page-2011-custom-landing-page is not a url, it is a template name. You can see the content inside the template my accessing the menu callback that using that template. (here it is : http://yoursite.com/pathname)

**Reference :** http://www.developerdoc.com/answer/add-template-menu-call-back